# Prove $\sin r = 3\sin \frac r3 - 4\sin^3 \frac r3$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, trigonometric-integrals

Does anyone know where this identity is explained and proved?

> The sine of an angle (specified in radians) can be computed by making use of the approximation $\sin x \approx x$ if $x$ is sufficiently small, and the trigonometric identity $$\sin x = 3 \sin\frac x3 - 4\sin^3\frac x3.$$

I have the solution to the exercise, I'm interested in the identity though.

Thanks

Comment: [Triple angle identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/triple-angle-identities/). This can be proven using the compound angle formulae.

Answer (score 3):

Use the identity $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b + \cos a\cos b$

$$\sin r=\sin \left(\frac r3 + \frac{2r}3\right)=\sin\frac r3\cos \frac{2r}3 + \cos\frac r3\sin\frac{2r}3 $$

Then, apply the identity $\sin2a = 2\sin a\cos a$ and $\cos 2a = 1-2\sin^2 a$

$$\begin{align}\sin r&=\sin\frac r3\left(1-2 \sin^2\frac{r}3\right) + \cos\frac r3\cdot 2\sin\frac{r}3 \cos\frac{r}3 \\
&=\sin\frac r3-2 \sin^3\frac{r}3 + 2\sin\frac{r}3 \left(1-\sin^2\frac{r}3\right)\\
&= 3\sin \frac r3 - 4\sin^3 \frac r3\end{align}$$

Comment: Beat me to it :) +1

Comment: Where is (r/3) + (2r)/3 coming from?  Thanks

Comment: @Nick - Note $r = \frac r3+ \frac{2r}3$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$3\sin\frac{r}{3}-4\sin^3\frac{r}{3}=\sin\frac{r}{3}\left(3-2\left(1-\cos\frac{2r}{3}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\sin\frac{r}{3}+2\sin\frac{r}{3}\cos\frac{2r}{3}=\sin\frac{r}{3}+\sin{r}-\sin\frac{r}{3}=\sin{r}.$$